# How to inject HTML into React JSX after function returns an HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a function that gets called on a Form submit.
This function returns a paragraph tag depending on the callback from an Axios POST request.

How do I inject this paragraph tag into my page so that it would display in the DOM?
Im sure it is quite simple but I am just struggling with what would be the best approach to do this

**FUNCTION:**

```
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: registerUsername,
        email: registerEmail,
        password: registerPassword,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/register",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data === "Username already exists") {
          return (
            <p className="text-sm text-red-600">Username already exists</p>
          );
        } else {
          <p className="text-sm text-red-600">Account registered</p>;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

**FORM:**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
            <label className="font-semibold">Username</label>
            <input
              placeholder="Username"
              name="username"
              className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
              onChange={(e) => setRegisterUsername(e.target.value)}
              {...register("username", {
                required: "An username is required",
              })}
            ></input>
            <p className="text-sm text-red-600">
              {errors?.username && errors.username.message}
            </p>

            <label className="font-semibold">Email</label>
            <input
              placeholder="E-mail"
              name="email"
              className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
              onChange={(e) => setRegisterEmail(e.target.value)}
              {...register("email", {
                required: "Please enter a valid e-mail",
              })}
            ></input>
            <p className="text-sm text-red-600">
              {errors?.email && errors.email.message}
            </p>

            <label className="font-semibold">Password</label>
            <input
              placeholder="Password"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
              onChange={(e) => setRegisterPassword(e.target.value)}
              {...register("password", {
                required: "Password must be min 8 or max 24 characters",
                min: 8,
                max: 24,
              })}
            ></input>
            <p className="text-sm text-red-600">
              {errors?.password && errors.password.message}
            </p>

            <label className="font-semibold">Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              type="password"
              name="confirmPassword"
              id="password"
              className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
              {...register("confirmPassword")}
              onChange={(e) => setRegisterUsername(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <p className="text-sm text-red-600">
              {errors?.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword.message}
            </p>

            <button
              // onClick={submitRegistration}
              type="submit"
              className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded w-full"
            >
              Create Account
            </button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***useState** will help in this*

```
const [error,setError]=useState("")
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
axios({
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    username: registerUsername,
    email: registerEmail,
    password: registerPassword,
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  url: "http://localhost:4000/register",
})
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data === "Username already exists") {
      return (
        setError("Username already exists")//Change here
      );
    } else {
      setError("Account registered")//Change here
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

};

**FORM:**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
{error &&  <p className="text-sm text-red-600">{error}</p>}
</form>
```